# Bamboo - script to read commit message

Tags: bash, git, shell, command, bamboo

I am planning to execute some task based on commit message. Need help reading commit message. like below which will give branch name

```
${bamboo.repository.git.branch}
```

I am trying to read **[Release-Minor]** from the commit message.

```
Pull request #614: [Release-Minor] - changes to minor functionality

Merge in branch from feature to master

* commit 'xxxxxxxxxxxx':
  [JIRA-1234] - changes to minor functionality
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would give you all commits short hashes you want:

```bash
git log \
  --oneline \
  --all-match \
  --fixed-strings \
  --regexp-ignore-case \
  --grep '[Release-Minor]'
```

See: `man git-log`

Comment: I believe OP was asking how to extract a particular `X-Y` version string from the commit message.